# Trouble inserting data into tables ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I'm trying to insert it into a table called bill but I keep getting errors no matter how much I what I do.

Below is the code that I'm using, when I tried replacing the total with NULL (for the sake of testing), it went through and inserted into the table. When I try to use any number no matter how long I keep getting "ORA-01722: invalid number"

```
insert into Bill ( Bill_code, Total, Start_date, End_date, Customer_ID )
VALUES('1373','5200','02-03-2022','02-05-2021','6724');
```

The number datatype has a precision of 16 with a scale of 2 and it's nullable.

Comment: What is the connection with PostgreSQL here? Please describe your setup.

Comment: Remove the quotes from the numbers in your query. Numbers are binary types in all databases. The only way you'd get such an error would be if you tried to store *strings* in numeric fields. That's a bug, plain and simple. Don't do it.

Comment: Same goes for dates. If you *must* use a date literal (ie string representation) **don't** use a localized format. Make sure you use the unambiguous ISO8601 and the correct syntax to interpret it as a date. In Oracle that's `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'`

Answer (score 2):

**ORA-01722: invalid number** clearly states that this is an **Oracle** error; what is that `postgres` tag doing here?

In Oracle - as far as I managed to recreate your test case (as you didn't post table description), it *works* correctly.

You should really use proper datatypes:

- as long as `bill_code` or `customer_id` *may be* strings,
- `total` certainly isn't (you said it is a number), while
- dates should be exactly that - `DATE` datatype

  - in that case, use date literal (as my example shows) or `to_date` function with appropriate format model. Don't rely on implicit datatype conversion. What is `02-03-2022`? Is it 2nd of March or 3rd of February? Could be both.

So:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE bill
  2  (
  3     bill_code     VARCHAR2 (10),
  4     total         NUMBER (16, 2),
  5     start_date    DATE,
  6     end_date      DATE,
  7     customer_id   VARCHAR2 (10)
  8  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO Bill (Bill_code,
  2                    Total,
  3                    Start_date,
  4                    End_date,
  5                    Customer_ID)
  6       VALUES ('1373',
  7               5200,
  8               DATE '2022-03-02',
  9               DATE '2021-05-02',
 10               '6724');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your column type is not varchar or any character based one, do not use quotes for inserting numbers.

insert into Bill ( Bill_code, Total, Start_date, End_date, Customer_ID ) VALUES('1373',5200,'02-03-2022','02-05-2021','6724');

Comment: You can specify a string for a numeric column so long as it can be implicitly cast to a number. The problem is elsewhere. I'm not saying using apostrophes (quote is a different character) is a good idea for numeric data, I'm only saying that it *can* succeed.

Comment: I also thought that removing the quotes will fix the problem but I'm still getting the same error regardless if I use quotes or not.

Comment: @AAALMARRI I just realized you're using postgresql. You should probably remove the apostrophes for the customer_id. I suspect that too is numeric. I saw `oracle-apex` and was misled. Maybe postgresql cannot implicitly coerce strings to numbers like `oracle` does. For that matter, you should describe the table and fix all of the numeric values. Maybe bill_code is also numeric.

Comment: @JeffHolt PostgreSQL wouldn't throw an `ORA-` error. All databases have numeric types too and avoiding quotes isn't just a good idea- it's critical. Otherwise the string will be interpreted using the server's locale and `123.450` can end up `123450`